# deducing inequality of polynomial degrees in a purely algebraic fashion

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be field and $R=k[\xi_1,\cdots,\xi_r]$ be an integral domain of transcendence degree $t$ over $k$. Let $l(R_n)$ be the length of the $n^{th}$ homogeneous component of $R$. Then for $n$ large enough, $l(R_n)$ is a polynomial of degree $d-1$ in $n$; this is the Hilbert polynomial ($l(\cdot)$) denotes the length function). Now, there are $\left(\begin{array}{c} n+t-1\\ t-1 \end{array}\right)$ linearly independent monomials of degree $n$ in $R$ and so $l(R_n) \ge \left(\begin{array}{c} n+t-1\\ t-1 \end{array}\right)$. Then Matsumura in his Commutative Ring Theory p. 96, concludes that $d \ge t$.

Question: I want to make sure i fully understand the reasoning behind the deduction $d \ge t$ from the inequality $l(R_n) \ge \left(\begin{array}{c} n+t-1\\ t-1 \end{array}\right)$. This is an inequality of polynomials in $n$ and is equivalent to $l(R_n) - \left(\begin{array}{c} n+t-1\\ t-1 \end{array}\right) \ge 0$. This says that the difference of two polynomials must be positive. If we use real analysis, this means that the coefficient of the leading term has to be positive, because at infinity the leading term prevails. This proves that $d \ge t$, however, this is not an algebraic argument. So i wonder if we could prove $d \ge t$ using a purely algebraic argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the fact, that a polynomial with negative leading term is eventually negative is not really an analytic argument, since you don't need limits. It doesn't even need $\mathbb{R}$, but is true and can be proven for polynomials on $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: But when you say "is eventually negative", it seems to me that you are using a limiting process :) I would like to see that proof you mention.

Comment: It just means "There is an $N$ such that for every $n>N$  $P(n)<0$ Also, hi :) the world is small

Comment: Can you prove it?

Comment: Without loss of generality, I show that my assumption holds for $P(n)=-x^m+a_{m-1}x^{m-1}\dots+a_0$. Let $x>\max\{1,m,ma_{m-1},ma_{m-2}\dots\}$. Then $P(x)<-x^m+\frac{x}{m}|x|^{m-1}+\dots+\frac{x}{m}a_0<-x^m+m\frac{x}{m}|x|^{m-1}<-x^m+|x|^m = 0$.

Comment: The right hand side of your first inequality is unclear. Its unclear what you mean.

Comment: fixed it, forget the $a_0$

Comment: I don't see how you obtain your second inequality.

Comment: I summarize $m$ terms. And every single one is smaller than $\frac{x}{m}|x|^{m-1}$ because $x>1$.

Comment: Nice proof Bananach!